# tikz coordinate shift within 'to path' not working

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to connect 2 point with zigzag line with a offset defined by xshift as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\tikzset{
    ann/.style = {/utils/exec=\tikzset{ann/.cd,#1},
        to path = {
            (\tikztostart)
             -- ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ann/x}] \tikztostart)
             |- (\tikztotarget)
        }
    },ann/.cd,x/.initial=1}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \node  (A) {A};
  \node at (5,5)  (B) {B};
  \draw[line width=5pt] (A) to[ann={x=2}] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But sounds like the xshift command doesn't do anything!
[image]

Comment: It does work but there is a confusion about the units, I think.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sounds like even if I hardcore it to 2cm, doesn't work either!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. First, you forgot the units, so `2` gets interpreted as `2pt`. Second, the starting node is a node, i.e. an extended object, but the path really starts at the border. In order to have finer control, you may thus introduce an auxiliary coordinate. You then get

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\tikzset{
    ann/.style = {/utils/exec=\tikzset{ann/.cd,#1},
        to path = {
            (\tikztostart) coordinate(aux)
             -- ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ann/x}]aux)
             |- (\tikztotarget)
        }
    },ann/.cd,x/.initial=1mm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \node  (A) {A};
  \node at (5,5)  (B) {B};
  \draw[line width=5pt] (A) to[ann={x=5mm}] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can clearly see, the thick line does not start at the center of the `A` node but at the boundary. This is why it is better to introduce the auxiliary coordinate.

You can get the same result without auxiliary coordinates by using `++`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\tikzset{
    ann/.style = {/utils/exec=\tikzset{ann/.cd,#1},
        to path = {
            (\tikztostart) 
             -- ++ (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ann/x},0)
             |- (\tikztotarget)
        }
    },ann/.cd,x/.initial=1mm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
  \node  (A) {A};
  \node at (5,5)  (B) {B};
  \draw[line width=5pt] (A) to[ann={x=5mm}] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```